How could we approximate $\int \frac{W(t) }{1+W(t)}\,\, \frac {\sin(t)} t \, dt$?
In a now deleted post appeared an interesting integral.
$$I=\int\frac 1 x \,\,\sin \left(\frac{\log (x)}{x}\right) \,dx$$ which does not make (too much) problems from a numerical point of view.
As one can expect, the plot of the integrand is not the most pleasnat we could find.
$$\frac{\log(x)}x=-t \quad\implies\quad x=\frac{W(t)}{t}\quad \implies \quad $$ $$I=\int \frac{W(t) }{1+W(t)}\,\, \frac {\sin(t)} t \, dt=\text{Si}(t)-\int \frac{1 }{1+W(t)}\,\, \frac {\sin(t)} t \, dt$$ which is much more pleasant to look at and even easier to integrate nmerically.
My question is : how could we approximate the integrand to have a decent approximation for the integral between $k\pi$ and $(k+1)\pi$ ?$k$ being a non negative integer.
Edit
Thanks to @Hume2's answer, the problem now reduces to
$$I=W(t)\,\sin(t)-\int W(t)\,\cos(t)\, dt$$
$$J_k=-\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} W(t)\,\cos(t)\, dt$$
Asymptotically, it seems that
$$|J_k| \sim \frac{1}{2 k}+\frac{3}{4k^2}+\frac{19}{4k^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^4}\right)$$

Is $k>0$ ? Is it an integer or any real number ?

@Sam. If you plot the function, I suppose that you will see that the interesting part is between the zero's of the integrand. So, yes, $k$ has to be a non negative integer. Thanks for pointing. Cheers :-)

Just spotted your question, Claude. It happens that I have used the relationship given by @Hume2 (under a slightly different form) in a recent answer of mine here to an interesting question : see equation (7) of my "second method"...

According to Wolfram Alpha:$$
\int\frac{W(t)}{(1+W(t))t}=W(t)+C
$$
So we can apply per-partes to the integral and we get:$$
I=W(t)\sin(t)-\int W(t)\cos(t)\mathrm dt
$$
If you are interested only in integrals between multiples of $\pi$, then the term before the integral cancels out. Can you continue from now on?

Guess what ? You made my day ! Thanks & cheers :-)

So, if we make $W(t) \sim \log(t)$  and use the bounds, we have a first order approximation for large $t$ and this leads to the sine integral

$\log(t)\cos(t)$ integrates to $\log(t)\sin(t)-\mathrm{Si}(t)+C$ and the first term cancels out, so yes.

Yes I know ! If you maka $W(t) \sim 1+W(t)$, you have the same
